# TypeError: user.save is not a function [mongoose]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my code, can't deal with this problem. Tried to get rid of this function, but nothing work.
code =>

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/blog_demo_2", {useNewUrlParser: true});

//post - content, title

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   content: String
});

var postModel = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

//user - email, name
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,
    posts: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Post"
        }
    ]
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

and here is the problem function, don't understand what causes an error. I thought that it was a problem with postModel, but nah:

```
postModel.create({
    title: "How to be fat like Andjelka Kozakivnayadura",
    content: "Eat burgers, pizzas, and Coke Cole bittcheeies"
}, function(err, post){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        User.find({email: "gangbit@protonmail.com"}, function(err, user){
           if (err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
               user.posts = user.posts || [];
               user.posts.push(post);
               user.save(function(err, data){
                   if (err){
                       console.log(err);
                   } else {
                       console.log(data);
                   }
               });
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post some error logs?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Associations/references.js:34:31
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4845:16
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Associations/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4283:12

Answer (score 1):

`User.find({email: "gangbit@protonmail.com"}, function(err, user){`

That returns an array of users, not single user.

You want `findOne` instead.

Next time, `console.log(user)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning an object using `Spread Operator {...someObj}`.

```
User.find({email: "gangbit@protonmail.com"}, function(err, user){
       if (err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           const userObj = {...user };
```

Now you can try to `push` data into `posts`. You can also `convert mongodB document to JS object`, using the function `toObject()`.

```
User.find({email: "gangbit@protonmail.com"}, function(err, user){
       if (err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           const userObj = user.toObject();
```